# Hide statusbar during splash screen

Tags: ios, swift, splash-screen

I'm trying to hide the statusbar during splash screen, which works fine when i add "Status bar is initially hidden" to plist and set value to YES, however this remove the statusBar from the enitre application, even though i've added "View controller-based status bar appearance" to plist and set value to NO and added following to appdelegate:

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
```

How can i remove the statusBar initially without removing it in the rest of the application?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is updated for Swift 3 of Xcode 8.3.3

In your Info.plist add the following key:

[image: info.plist]

Then in your AppDelegate file add the following in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` section:

```
func application(_application:UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool { 
      UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
      return true 
}
```

That should sort out your problem.

You can also configure the launch colour in your project Build Settings if this is a problem for you:

[image: buildOptions]

Comment: For ObjectiveC and Xcode 10 you can re-enable the StatusBar with `UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarHidden = NO;`

Comment: `Setter for 'isStatusBarHidden' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden]`

Comment: It seems as if `UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false` is not necessary, and the status bar will show up (after Launch Screen) anyway.

Answer (score 28):

In Swift 4
In Info.plist add:

> `Status bar is initially hidden` `YES`

Comment: Works perfect for me

Answer (score 12):

In your Project Settings -> General-> Deployment Info, check "Hide status bar" field.

[image]

Next in your view controller override [- prefersStatusBarHidden](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prefersStatusBarHidden) method, like this:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
   return false
}
```

Comment: This solution seems closest.
I just needed to check the "Hide Status Bar" as mentioned above and then this was not needed:

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
   return false
}

Comment: error, use:
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
        return false
    }
instead

Answer (score 9):

**Just add the highlighted line into your Info.plist file and it'll work for Swift 4:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3

First Hide Status bar from Project->Target as following

[image]

then unhide status bar in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
func application(_application:UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool { 
      UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
      return true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation)
```

Comment: guess they really want you to use UIViewController-based status bar

Answer (score 0):

To also hide on iPad, also set the `UIStatusBarHidden~ipad` key in the Info.plist to `YES`.